# Tensorflow: Can not convert a function into a Tensor or Operation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have read through previous strings.  My data are in the form of an array fed to a placeholder.  Trying to convert the data to a tensor before feeding produces a different (inverse) error message. Other solutions similarly do not seem to work in this situation.  Here is minimal code.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.factorization import KMeans

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name="X")

data = np.random.randn(2,10)

def lump(X):
    # Build KMeans graph
    kmeans = KMeans(inputs=X, num_clusters=k, distance_metric='cosine',
            use_mini_batch=True)
    (all_scores, cluster_idx, scores, cluster_centers_initialized,      cluster_centers_var, init_op,
    train_op) = kmeans.training_graph()
    cluster_idx = cluster_idx[0] # fix for cluster_idx being a tuple
    avg_distance = tf.reduce_mean(scores)

    return cluster_idx, scores

# Initialize the variables (i.e. assign their default value)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    idx, d = sess.run(lump,feed_dict={X: data})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, you can't evaluate just `lump`, because it's a *function* (returning tensors), not a *tensor* or an *op*. You probably meant to do something like this:

```
cluster_idx, scores = lump(X)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  idx, d = sess.run([cluster_idx, scores], feed_dict={X: data})
```

Note that `lump()` is invoked before `tf.global_variables_initializer()`, because it defines new variables in the graph, so they must be initialized.

The code still fails, because `lump` is clearly not finished and has issues with dimensions, but it is the right way to evaluate something in a session.